# SQL - Using CUBE grand total per row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL (CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(PurchaseDate)), NULL) [Month],
    ISNULL (Brand, CASE 
                      WHEN MONTH(PurchaseDate) IS NOT NULL THEN 'Monthly SubTotal'
                      WHEN Brand IS NULL THEN 'Grand Total'
                      ELSE 'N/A'
                   END) [Brand], SUM(Price) [Total Amount]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Purchase_Items] 
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(PurchaseDate), Brand WITH CUBE
```

I want to change it to Grand Total on selected box. How to code it or change the string on it.

Comment: You edit undid the improvements recently made by another member. If you inspect the edit history you'll see how they did it.

Comment: The total per Brand is already calculated e.g. `Apple: 170,000+70,000+170,000 = 410,000` can you explain which calculation is missing?  Also to get best results from you questions supply "sample data" and "expected result" (but not as images). Suggest you look at the help link in the footer on how to format and how best to ask questions

Comment: @Used_By_Already Yes the total per Brand is already calculated, but i want to change the string on total per Brand. For example the total of the Apple, i want to change the string value 'Apple' to 'Grand Total for apple'.

Comment: I believe `with cube` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first get your data (a simpler version of what you have above) you can then use that as a data source to do conversions/updates as needed.

I'm using a CTE here, but you can do it with subqueries just as well.

```
WITH MonthTotals AS
    (SELECT
       MONTH(PurchaseDate) [Month],
       [Brand],
       SUM(Price) [Total Amount]
    FROM [dbo].[Purchase_Items] 
    GROUP BY MONTH(PurchaseDate), Brand WITH CUBE
    )
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), mt.[Month]) AS [Month],
       CASE WHEN mt.[Month] IS NULL AND mt.[Brand] IS NULL THEN 'Grand Total'
            WHEN mt.[Month] IS NULL THEN 'Grand total for ' + mt.[Brand]
            WHEN mt.[Brand] IS NULL THEN 'Monthly total'
            ELSE mt.[Brand] END AS [Brand]
       [Total Amount]
  FROM MonthTotals mt;
```

Note though that CUBE is usually done in SQL Server like the following - it means you can select which columns you CUBE by (or rollup, etc)

```
GROUP BY CUBE(MONTH(PurchaseDate), Brand)
```

---

**IMPORTANT UPDATE** following @MartinSmith's comment below

Martin Smith gave the advice that I should use the `GROUPING` function. In reviewing that function, he is 100% correct (and thankyou Martin - this is my learning for today).

For reference, the GROUPING function indicates (with a 1 or 0) whether the row is an aggregate row or not (e.g., one of the rows added by ROLLUP/CUBE/GROUPING SETs).

I also made a mistake with subtotals for months - put it in the wrong column.

Therefore, the update should be the following (note also that I have included the 'original' vales from the CUBE for month and brand as well)

```
WITH MonthTotals AS
    (SELECT
       MONTH(PurchaseDate) [Month],
       [Brand],
       SUM(Price) [Total Amount],
       GROUPING(MONTH(PurchaseDate)) AS Agg_flag_Month,
       GROUPING([Brand]) AS Agg_flag_Brand
    FROM [dbo].[Purchase_Items] 
    GROUP BY CUBE(MONTH(PurchaseDate), Brand)
    )
SELECT  [Month] AS Orig_Month,
        [Brand] AS Orig_Brand,
        CASE WHEN Agg_flag_Month = 1 THEN 'Grand total for ' + mt.[Brand]
            ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), mt.[Month]) 
            END AS [Month],
       CASE WHEN Agg_flag_Month * Agg_flag_Brand = 1 THEN 'Grand Total'
            WHEN Agg_flag_Brand = 1 THEN 'Monthly total'
            ELSE mt.[Brand] 
            END AS [Brand],
       [Total Amount]
  FROM MonthTotals mt;
```

Comment: My problem is solved, thank you so much for the code. For the last question how do i get back the 'Monthly Subtotal' ?

Comment: You can put another line into the CASE expression - I'll update the answer with the additional row.

Comment: you should use the `GROUPING` function

Comment: I wasn't aware of that function @Martin - but on reading about it, I completely agree that it should be used. So thankyou for the very useful feedback. My answer has been updated appropriately.